# How do I stop Django development server from restarting?

Tags: django

I want Django development server to exit when an error happens. But whenever the server exits, it restarts. I tried to kill the process using os.kill(os.getpid, 9) which does not work. I tried sys.exit, os._exit, and raised errors and none of them works.

Notes:
Since the program doesn't only run on Linux, so ideally I wish not to use anything like bash. Also I don't want to disrupt other processes.

Comment: `pkill -9 python` :)

Comment: Try to run the server with option [`--noreload`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload).

Comment: The ``--noreload`` option stops automatic process reloading when you make code changes. That said, if disabled, it may have a side effect of allowing ``os._exit()`` to work as there will not be a parent and child, only parent. It still will not automatically exit on exceptions though.

Comment: Question I would have is why you would want to have process exit when an exception occurs. Just curious. The whole idea with web applications usually is that an error only causes failure of the one request and otherwise the server keeps running.

Comment: I use webpack dev server for frontend build. Python runserver only exits when webpack dev server exits. In this case it is unnecessary to keep the app running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development server doesn't restart on error, it just handles the exception and goes on, just as production server does. This is the way it's supposed to be – HTTP is stateless, error in one request shouldn't affect the next one.

So you need to be aware that whatever you're doing, **you're probably abusing the `runserver`**, and there's almost surely a better way to do it.

That said:

There are several places on which the server is prevented from exiting on error.

First, Django wraps each request in the `django.core.handlers.exception.convert_exception_to_response` function, which catches every `Exception` and turns it into a nice response. So to pass through this, you need to raise an error [not derived from `Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), like a `KeyboardInterrupt` or a `SystemExit`.

Then there's `django.core.servers.basehttp.ServerHandler`, which derives from `wsgiref.handers.BaseHandler`, which wraps the request in a `try: ... except: ...` to catch all exceptions, and, again, turn them into responses. Since you probably still want to get that response, you'll have to modify the `handle_error` method to raise an error again *after* generating an error response.

Unfortunately, there's a lot of coupling there. The `ServerHandler` class is hard-coded into `django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIRequestHandler.handle`, which is hard-coded into `django.core.server.basehttp.run`, which is hard-coded into `django.core.management.commands.runserver`. So you'd either have to copy all of that code (which is basically what Django does, copying some code from `wsgiref`) or you're left with monkey-patching.

And then there's still `django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIServer`, which is a subclass of `socketserver.BaseServer`. The exception we just re-raised now goes to `WSGIServer.handle_error`, which tries to turn it into a response and go on. So you need to override that.

Then it should work, provided you run the server without threads and auto-reloading, by running a custom command derived from runserver, as in:

```
import sys
from django.core.management.commands import runserver
from django.core.servers.basehttp import ServerHandler, is_broken_pipe_error, WSGIServer


good_handle_error = ServerHandler.handle_error
def bad_handle_error(self):
    if not is_broken_pipe_error():
        good_handle_error(self)
        sys.exit(1)
ServerHandler.handle_error = bad_handle_error


class BadWSGIServer(WSGIServer):
    def handle_error(self, request, client_address):
        if is_broken_pipe_error():
            super().handle_error(self, request, client_address)
        else:
            sys.exit(1)


class Command(runserver.Command):
    server_cls = BadWSGIServer

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        options['use_reloader'] = False
        options['use_threading'] = False
        super().handle(*args, **options)
```